# Sending HTTP POST request using sockets

Tags: ios, sockets, http, inputstream, outputstream

I am currently learning Stream Programming Guide from Apple to make use of sockets. Can you guys provide me some reference link which talks about sending HTTP request (GET & POST) via sockets(input & output streams)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 2):

Try searching a little yourself before posting a question like this.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

[Objective C : Post/Get Request using Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079872/objective-c-post-get-request-using-socket)

[Make a Http Request With Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276668/make-a-http-request-with-sockets)

UPDATED:

http://www.example-code.com/ios/http_post_json.asp

http://blog.stathat.com/2011/11/28/http-post-in-many-languages.html

Comment: I went through these links earlier. They only mention about GET request. I want to know about sending POST and other types of requests via sockets